# Show a time-stamp in one cell when another cell is updated in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I want to time stamp when a cell was filled out in the column to the right of only certain columns.  We use a simple spread sheet to keep inventory and I'd like to know when someone takes something or checks it back in for accountability reasons.  I found a script that adds a note, but that gets very annoying when I only want it to apply in certain areas.  So when someone updates columns C,D,I, or J with their initials, I'd like a time-stamp to show up in column E or K.  Is this possible with a script?  I've attached an image for an idea with the red squares showing where I'd like the time/date showing.[image]

Answer (score 7):

All you need is this short script

```
function getDate() {
  return new Date();
}
```

And then you can put this equation into E1: `=getDate(C1:D1)` which you can then drag down. You may also want to change the format for column E and select a date format where both date and time are displayed.

Comment: When some cell in the Spreadsheet is changed e.g. C1, then all cells that use C1 in an equation are updated automatically. So if you put `=getDate(C1:D1)` into E1, E1 will get updated whenever C1 or D1 are changed. Otherwise it keeps it's current value.